# How do I use Scala Hashmaps and Options together correctly?

Tags: scala

My code snippets are below

```
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap

val crossingMap = new HashMap[String, Option[Long]]
val crossingData: String = ...
val time: Long = crossingMap.get(crossingData).getOrElse(0)
```

I get the following compile error

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : Any
required: Long
val time: Long = crossingMap.get(crossingData).getOrElse(0)
```

Comment: Hint: The type of `crossingMap.get(crossingData)` is `Option[Option[Long]]`.

Comment: If you map a `String` to `None`, you can as well not have the mapping in the first place, can't you? That's why (as Kipton Barros suggests) you probably want a `HashMap[String, Long]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want `crossingMap` to contain `String -> Long` pairs. Then you can do the following,

```
val crossingMap = new HashMap[String, Long]
val crossingData: String = ""
val time: Long = crossingMap.getOrElse(crossingData, 0)
```

If you really do want the `crossingMap` values to have type `Option[Long]`, then you'll have to do something like,

```
val crossingMap = new HashMap[String, Option[Long]]
val crossingData: String = ""
val time: Long = crossingMap.getOrElse(crossingData, None).getOrElse(0)
```