# How do I use Scala Hashmaps and Tuples together correctly?

Tags: scala

My code is as follows

```
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap
type CrossingInterval = (Date, Date)
val crossingMap = new HashMap[String, CrossingInterval]
val crossingData: String = ...
```

Firstly why does the following line compile?

```
val time = crossingMap.getOrElse(crossingData, -1)
```

I would have thought -1 would have been an invalid value

Secondly how do I do a basic check such as the following

```
if (value exists in map) {
}
else {
}
```

In Java I would just check for null values. I'm not sure about the proper way to do it in Scala

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use Scala Hashmaps and Options together correctly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047145/how-do-i-use-scala-hashmaps-and-options-together-correctly)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typing your code in the interpreter shows why the first statement compiles:

```
type Date = String
scala> val time = crossingMap.getOrElse(crossingData, -1)
time: Any = -1
```

Basically, `getOrElse` on a `Map[A, B]` (here `B = CrossingDate`) accepts a parameter of any type `B1 >: B`: that means that `B1` must be a supertype of `B`. Here `B1 = Any`, and -1 is of course a valid value of type `Any`. In this case you actually want to have a type declaration for `time`.

For testing whether a key belongs to the map, just call the contains method. An example is below - since Date was not available, I simply defined it as an alias to String.

```
scala> crossingMap.contains(crossingData)
res13: Boolean = false
scala> crossingMap += "" -> ("", "")
res14: crossingMap.type = Map("" -> ("",""))
//Now "" is a map of the key
scala> crossingMap.contains("")
res15: Boolean = true
```

If you want to check whether a value is part of the map, the simplest way is to write this code:

```
crossingMap.values.toSet.contains("")
```

However, this builds a `Set` containing all values. EDIT: You can find a better solution for this subproblem in Kipton Barros comment.

Comment: Here's another way to check if `x` is a value in `crossingMap`: `crossingMap.values.exists(x ==)`

Comment: You're right, that makes more sense and I should have thought of it. I removed my imperative solution as it was really ugly anyway.

Comment: It seems strange that there's an `exists` method but not a `contains` method in trait `Iterable`. Especially since the definition of `contains` in trait `SeqLike` is defined as `exists(_ == x)`

Comment: Indeed, it seems that even `Traversable[T].contains(t: T)` should be defined (since `exists` is defined in `Traversable`).

However, I realized a serious problem: `Map[A, B]` extends `Traversable[(A, B)]` and would thus have a `contains(t: (A, B))` method, which we really don't want. One could define `contains(t: ContainsT)`, with `ContainsT` being an abstract type member; but that would be still too inconvenient to use.